# No packages found for TeamCity NuGet feed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, teamcity, teamcity-10

I'm using TeamCity 10 and have the NuGet server enabled through the TeamCity Adminstration screens. I have the public feed turned off. My build artifacts (NuGet packages) are being published to the feed and I can see them in XML form by navigating to `mybuildserver:port/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages()` in the browser.

When I add `mybuildserver:port/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc` as a NuGet source in Visual Studio (Enterprise 2015 Update 3) it prompts me for my TeamCity credentials which I enter correctly and adds the source, but it shows

> No packages found

My account is an Admin on TeamCity.

How come I can see the XML NuGet feed with several packages but they don't show up in Visual Studio?

I've also tried `PM> Get-Package -ListAvailable` from the command line. But get

> No packages found in the current package source.

Comment: Are there only pre-release NuGet packages on Team City and if so do you have the include prerelease checkbox checked?

Comment: @Matt Yes! And of course they're hidden by default. I did some digging around and discovered it was the version numbers being generated by GitVersion which were causing them to be pre-release. A version number with something like `-patch` or `-beta` will be considered as a pre-release version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Matt Ward. Only the non-pre-release NuGet Packages will display in Visual Studio by default.

You could set the Visual Studio 2015 to display the prerelease packages in NuGet Package Manager UI by check the "Include prerelease" option in Package Manager page.

[image]